# Azure Request Increase to quota cap

Tags: azure

Does anyone know how to increase the quota cap for an Azure Pay as you go subscription.  I have used the Request Increase button at the top right of Usage + quotas multiple times, however have not received any communication from Microsoft nor has my quota changed.

I am simply requesting more vCPUs so that i can purchase more virtual machines with the specs that I need.

Any help or advice anyone can offer would be great.

Thanks
Deuan

Answer (score 0):

Well, I will answer my own question.

In my instance, the support emails coming back from microsoft were marked as Junk.  Interesting that MS don't ensure that genuine emails from Microsoft are not marked as Junk when using Microsoft office 365.

The irony is beyond comprehension.

Thanks ME!
:)